# Showing sequential text in matlab

Tags: matlab, text, psychtoolbox

i'm using matlab (psychtoolbox), i need to show many textual stories. each story is made by 5 parts that need to appear in a sequence (part1 - 6 sec - part 2 - 6 sec...). at the end of each story the subject is asked to answer a series of question (by pressing keys on the keyboard).

my question is: how can i randomize the stories keeping the sequential structure for each fixed?
my problem is that i want to randomize the stories but the structure for each has to remain fixed. i was thinking of making txt files with a part of the story in every row. in this way i'll only have to ask the code to display the first row, then wait, then display the second and so on. but so far i'didnt manage to do this.

i really need to do this in a short time. help here would be really appreciated.

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

make a cell array with your segments

```
X = {'this is part one of the first story' 'part 2 of first' 'part 3 of 1st';'this is part one of the 2nd story' 'part 2 of second' 'part 3 of 2nd' }
```

then you can adress them like this:

```
>> X{1, 1}

ans =

this is part one of the first story

>> X{1, 2}

ans =

part 2 of first
```

in the next step you randomize the first index, then you iterate the 2nd from 1 to 5